# Google Analytics cant find tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, tomcat7, vaadin

I have a problem with google analytics:

I implemented the tracking code like this:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'ransoft.at']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
```

just the way it should be implemented (according to goole).

The tracking code is on the side, but google analytics can't find it (Google Analytics: Tracking Info: Tracking not installed!)

Just see for yourself: http://www.ransoft.at

Google Analytics says, that i dont have the tracking code installed on my website.

Google Analytics: Property Settings:

- Default URL: http://www.ransoft.at

The website is powered by Vaadin7 and is running on tomcat7.

Pleas help me, i am quite lost here.

Comment: I'm actually not seeing any ga.js code on ransoft.at. Have a look at the live source code yourself. Are you seeing it? Has the code been uploaded and the server been refreshed?

Comment: I'm seeing the ga.js in the header. Its embedded like this:<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">

Comment: OK, I see that gets added at some point. I'm not seeing the rest of the code get executed though - the part you have saved as myLibrary.addGoogleAnalytics(). Do you just define that function, or do you actually execute it somewhere? Also, this particular website is probably well suited to a setup with [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) since the links lead to areas that act like new pages but do not actually cause a page refresh.

Comment: the myLibrary.addGoogleAnalytics() is being executet on startup. Like this: 

Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("myLibrary.addGoogleAnalytics();");

This is a Vaadin 7 feature and this works just fine.
This code is also being executet, because otherwise the ga.js would not be there. I dont know about virtual pageviews...but i doubt that this is the problem of the ga integration.

Comment: Are you seeing data in your GA account? If so, the implementation is probably fine and GA is just not detecting the installation because of the unconventional setup.

Comment: unfortunately not. i just read that sometimes ga needs some time to check if the tracking code is installed. Additionally I found some other bug in my webapp: <!Doctype htlm> is missing, maybe that is the problem after all?

Comment: The GA debuggers shows no calls to the utm.gif-file that's used for tracking, so I'd say the code does not work.  It might simply be that asynchronous google code and loading via bootstrapping do not mix very well.

Comment: ok...now i see data in my ga account. i changed the ga integration with a add-on: https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/googleanalyticstracker... now i can see data, but it still says that the tracking is not installed. Maybe it need some time to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to get google analytics running.

Google Analytics was not able to find my tracking code in the website. With the [GoogleAnalyticsTracker Add-on](http://vaadin.com/directory/-/directory/addon/googleanalyticstracker) the data was sent to GA, but the tracking information did say that the tracking code was not installed.

The problem was the missing [tracking code](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=1008080) in the Bootstrap Page.
The solution was to create a new VaadinServlet, where i created a new BootstrapListener. Something like this:

```
public class MyVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(new SessionInitListener() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
                event.getSession().addBootstrapListener(new BootstrapListener() {

                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void modifyBootstrapPage(BootstrapPageResponse response) {
                        // Adding Google Analytics to BootstrapPage header
                        head.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                                      "var _gaq = _gaq || [];"+
                                      "_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);" +
                                      "_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);" +
                                      "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/']);" +
                                      "(function() { " +
                                        "var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;" +
                                        "ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';" +
                                        "var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);" +
                                      "})();"+
                                    "</script>");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void modifyBootstrapFragment(BootstrapFragmentResponse response) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For further Information see: [Customizing Startup page in a Vaadin Application](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing%20the%20startup%20page%20in%20an%20application)
With this solution the data is being send to Google Analytics and the tracking code is also being recognized by Google Analytics.

There are probably some easier ways to do that in a Vaadin 7 Application, but this works for me. Thought I let you know that.

regards